# How to get renamed enum name from enum value?

Tags: rust, serde

So I have

```
#[derive(Deserialize, Clone, Debug, Copy)]
pub enum ComparisonOperators {
    #[serde(rename = "=")]
    EQ,
    #[serde(rename = "!=")]
    NEQ,
    #[serde(rename = ">")]
    GT,
    #[serde(rename = ">=")]
    GE,
    #[serde(rename = "<")]
    LT,
    #[serde(rename = "<=")]
    LE,
}
```

I want to get from `let i = ComparisonOperators::GE` to `">="`. Can I do this by not adding a mapper?

Comment: The `rename` is just for serializing/deserializing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the `Serialize` tag, and then use the `serde_json` to serialize to a `String` as per your attributes renaming:

```rust
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};
use serde_json; // 1.0.78

#[derive(Deserialize, Serialize, Clone, Debug, Copy)]
pub enum ComparisonOperators {
    #[serde(rename = "=")]
    EQ,
    #[serde(rename = "!=")]
    NEQ,
    #[serde(rename = ">")]
    GT,
    #[serde(rename = ">=")]
    GE,
    #[serde(rename = "<")]
    LT,
    #[serde(rename = "<=")]
    LE,
}

fn main() {
    let tag = serde_json::to_string(&ComparisonOperators::EQ).unwrap();
    println!("{tag}");
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=886a84e4945688cafbc7c1cefda96d3e)

You can even implement display for your enum based on that:

```rust
impl fmt::Display for ComparisonOperators {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> fmt::Result {
        write!(f, "{}", serde_json::to_string(self).unwrap())
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=04f1f00ff114bfa064e6c92bac69fe25)

Remember that `Display` gives you a [`ToString`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/trait.ToString.html) implementation for free.

Comment: the above will print values _with_ quotes, ie: "=" including the quotes.